# How to launch Vim in Python interpreter?

Tags: python, vim

In Ruby there is a gem called `interactive_editor` which allows entering a vim session when entering `vi` in Ruby interpreter.

Literally we need to require [`interactive_editor.rb`](https://github.com/jberkel/interactive_editor/blob/master/lib/interactive_editor.rb) in `~/.irbrc` file, like this:

```
require '~/interactive_editor.rb'
```

And we are done. When we do `vi` in interactive session; vim is launched. As soon as we quit the editor, the code inside the vim session is executed. [Here is more information about running vim within irb](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/running-vim-within-irb/).

So, is there any equivalent to that in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from os import system as sh
def vim(fname): sh('vim ' + fname)
```

A possible way of (re)loading the module:

```
import imp
from os import system as sh

def _vim(fname, globs):
    sh('vim ' + fname)
    (dirname, _, basename) = fname.rpartition('/')
    modname = basename.rpartition('.')[0]
    m = imp.load_source(modname, fname)
    globs[modname] = m
```

and anytime you import this into the interpreter, it is recommended to make a wrapper manually:

```
def vim(fname): _vim(fname, globals())
```

because `globals()` called in a python file holds the file's globals, not the interpreter's. I know, it's not elegant. But I'd recommend to reload module manually like `reload(modname)`, it gives you more control, though may be tedious.

Comment: Code is not interpreted as soon as I exit vim. BTW its very near to what I want :)

Answer (score 3):

The vim-ipython plugin is a two-way integration between IPython and Vim.

Quoting from the readme file on https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython:

> Using this plugin, you can send lines or whole files for IPython to
>   execute, and also get back object introspection and word completions
>   in Vim, like what you get with: `object?<enter>` and `object.<tab>` in
>   IPython.

Here is a demo of the plugin: http://pirsquared.org/vim-ipython/.

Comment: Tab completion is not really I want, and I only want to use pure Python interpreter.

Comment: @SantoshKumar You can use `Ipython` shell with any python interpreter - http://ipython.org/faq.html#can-ipython-run-under-ironpython-pypy-jython-other-python-interpreters, it is simply more configurable than the standard python shell.